# Is there a name for this kind of functions? $f(x,y) = z \iff x=g(y,z)$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, euclidean-geometry

Let $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$, if there exists $g: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ such that, for all $x,y,z\in \mathbb R$, $$f(x,y)=z \iff x=g(y,z).$$ Is there a name for such $f$'s and is there a name for this $g$? I think this is somehow similar to the concept of inverse functions, but not identically the same.

Comment: I don’t know if there is a name for it *f* and *g*, but you can say the relation between *x*, *y* and *z* is **separable** for both *x* and *z*.

Comment: In general , there is no universal name for this. In Particular , I think there is a close match thinking about Encryption + Decryption : given a value $x$ , we can Encrypt it to $z$ using a Key $y$ ; We can then Decrypt $z$ to $x$ using the same Key $y$. [[ https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/mathematics/decryption-function ]] + [[ https://medium.com/codeclan/what-are-encryption-keys-and-how-do-they-work-cc48c3053bd6#:~:text=a%20reciprocal%20cipher-,Symmetric-key%20encryption,both%20use%20a%20symmetric-key. ]]